# How to use regular expression in makefile if statement?

Tags: regex, makefile

I'm simply trying to prompt the and get some input, then take action based on that input in a makefile.

I need to check if input is "Y", or "y". Anything else should exit.

Currently I have the following, that works, but is a bit long-winded. I was hoping to make it more concise by using a simple regular expression:

```
if [ "$$INSTALL_GLOBALS" != "y" ] && [ "$$INSTALL_GLOBALS" != "Y" ]; then \
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex character class.

```
if [[ "$$INSTALL_GLOBALS" =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
```

`^` in regex asserts that we are at the start and `$` asserts thta we are at the end of a line. `[yY]` matches a single character whether it may be capital `Y` or small `y`.

Comment: That's pretty much what I had tried, but I get a syntax error. https://gist.github.com/SeerUK/cbfee9b01b449586885a

Comment: you must give space before `]]`

Comment: Argh! That's it, it's the `$`, it thinks it's a variable, and removes it and the space.

Comment: Escaping `$` as `$$` is a little better ... but not much.